# Pass dropdown list into a method

Tags: c#

I have the following code `LoadRegistrations();` to populate a `DropDownList` with values from a SQL database.

I will be likely to use this several times in different places so wanted to write a method to take care of it, instead of copying this method and changing minor details.

I've got as far as populating the `DataTable` but I'm not sure how to go about passing a `DropDownList` & the `DataTextField` + `DataValueField` into it and binding the data. Please explain what I have to do

Original Method

```
private void LoadRegistrations()
    {
        DataTable reg = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString1"].ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select vehicleID, regNo from dbo.Vehicles order by regNo Asc", con);
                adapter.Fill(reg);
                ddreg.DataSource = reg;
                ddreg.DataTextField = "regNo";
                ddreg.DataValueField = "vehicleID";
                ddreg.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Error handling to be done
            }

        }
    }
```

New Method

```
private DataTable PopulateDropdown(string connectionString, DataTable datatable, string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
          //What do I do here? I want to bind to a dropdown list passed into this method
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
        return dt;
}
```

ASP to generate dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddreg"  CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Registration Number>" Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Have you tried, well, adding a `DropDownList` as a method parameter?

Comment: If I try that, I get a `type of namespace missing` error. It's codebehind for a child of a master page, not sure if i'm missing a required assembly but it seems OK to utilise a dropdown list object in my first method, within the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a method with parameters:

```
private DataTable PopulateDropdown(string connectionString, DataTable datatable, string query)
```

If you want to pass a `DropDownList` to that method, do exactly what you already do and add a parameter:

```
private DataTable PopulateDropdown(string connectionString, DataTable datatable, string query, DropDownList myDropDownList)
```

Then in the method you can refer to `myDropDownList`:

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = dt;
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

When calling the method, you'd pass it the `DropDownList` you want to modify:

```
PopulateDropDown(someConnectionString, someDataTableYouDoNotUse, someQuery, ddreg);
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you :) I had to reference `System.Web.UI.WebControls` as well but it now works as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataTable PopulateDropdown(string connectionString, DataTable datatable, string query, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList yourDropdownList)
    { 
       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        yourDropdownList.DataSource = dt;
        yourDropdownList.DataBind();
        return dt;

    }
```

Comment: I would end up with that repeated in my Page_Load method though when I really wanted to just call something like `PopulateDropdown(connectionString, DataTable,query,yourDropdownList, textField, valueField);`